# Tetrad basis: a doubt on "Comoving" and "Static" tetrads

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

In the awesome [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.4184) $[1]$, Müller then gives us a plethora of spacetimes and their basic geometrical objects like the form of the line element, Christoffel symbols, Krestchmann scalars and so on. Futhermore, we can see that in the paper Müller also gives us tetrads.

So, I would like to ask what is a **Static Local Tetrad** and **Comoving Local Tetrad**?

$$* * *$$

$[1]$ MÜLLER.T; *Catalogue of Spacetimes*;     arXiv:0904.4184